# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 - Missing Power off Option in Power settings

Tags: 16.04, power-management

My machine is having Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 which is upgraded from 14.04.

[image: Power Menu]

Even though my Power menu mentions "Suspend and Power off", I don't have a power off option. I am not able to set my system to power-off on critical battery level.

I can edit the same options through dconf-editor, but it is not having any effect. The system is not powering off on the critical battery level. This was working fine when I was in 14.04. What can I do to poweroff my system at a certain critical battery level?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have just installed Ubuntu, I had the same problem, search for "power options" in search area (invoked by pressing the start key on the physical keyboard). as soon as you click on them, your setting options will be extended including power options.